# How to remove the [1]s, [[1]]s and double quotes from a csv data in R?

Tags: regex, r, csv, format, read.csv

I've a CSV file. It contains the output of some previous R operations, so it is filled with the index numbers (such as [1], [[1]]). When it is read into R, it looks like this, for example:

```
        V1
1                                                                                                           [1] 789
2                                                                                                             [[1]]
3                                                           [1] "PNG"        "D115"    "DX06"    "Slz"
4                                                                                                           [1] 787
5                                                                                                             [[1]]
6                                                                       [1] "D010"           "HC"
7                                                                                                           [1] 949
8                                                                                                             [[1]]
9                                                                       [1] "HC" "DX06"
```

(I don't know why all that wasted space between line number and the output data)

I need the above data to appear as follows (without [1] or [[1]] or " " and with the data placed beside its corresponding number, like):

```
789 PNG,D115,DX06,Slz
787 D010,HC
949 HC,DX06
```

(possibly the `789` and its corresponding data `PNG,D115,DX06,Slz` should be separated by a tab.. and like that for each row)

How to achieve this in R?

Comment: It would be better (and easier) to fix the data export that created this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could create a grouping variable ('indx'), `split` the 'V1' column using the grouping index after removing the parentheses part in the beginning as well as the quotes within the string `"`.  Assuming that we need the first column as the numeric element, and the second column as the non-numeric part, we can use regex to replace the space with `,` (as showed in the expected result, and then `rbind` the list elements.

```
indx <- cumsum(c(grepl('\\[\\[', df1$V1)[-1], FALSE))
 do.call(rbind,lapply(split(gsub('"|^.*\\]', '', df1$V1), indx),
         function(x) data.frame(ind=x[1],
    val=gsub('\\s+', ',', gsub('^\\s+|\\s+$', '',x[-1][x[-1]!=''])))))

 #   ind               val
 #1  789 PNG,D115,DX06,Slz
 #2  787           D010,HC
 #3  949           HC,DX06
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("[1] 789", "[[1]]", 
 "[1] \"PNG\"        \"D115\"    \"DX06\"    \"Slz\"", 
 "[1] 787", "[[1]]", "[1] \"D010\"           \"HC\"", "[1] 949", 
 "[[1]]", "[1] \"HC\" \"DX06\"")), .Names = "V1", 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
 "7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: That was a fabulous code (although pretty complex for a beginner like me understand perfectly) Will study it further. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, a command-line fix using either sed/perl/egrep -o is less pain:

```
sed -e 's/.*\][ \t]*//' dirty.csv > clean.csv
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out an alternative.. I'm pretty beginner at R. Will check this out too and learn. Thank you so much.